# Smoke+Fire sim for thruster using wind

Tags: smoke-simulation, force-fields, fire

I'm having a problem with the smoke and fire sim, after a few seconds the thrust stream "explodes" and then only sparks appear.
I used a plane as inflow and a cube as domain, all with default settings.
Then I added a wind force field oriented downwards.

[image]

[image]